# Notification progress in tray from command line

Tags: kde, opensuse, kde5

OpenSuse 42.1 + KDE 5

I use kdialog in my script to inform me on the process start/end

```
#!/bin/sh
while inotifywait -r -e modify -e create -e delete ~/www/gruz.org.uab/www/; do
    kdialog --passivepopup 'Started' --title 'UNISON update';
    unison   -ui text -auto -batch gruz.org.uab
    kdialog --passivepopup 'Finished' --title 'UNISON update';
done
```

But the popups cover some display area and I want to replace them with a progress indicator in the system tray, like when copying a file.

http://static.xscreenshot.com/small/2016/08/04/13/screen_c0544580363c95b1458ba32ad0dcb741

I read about something like **qdbus org.kde.JobViewServer.requestView** , but didn't manage to implement it due to the lack of knowledge.

Can you please provide command line example (or other equivalent) to

- preform a process
- start indicator in the tray
- stop indicator on finish

Thank you, dear All

Answer (score 2):

The problem with using `qdbus org.kde.JobViewServer.requestView` from a shell script is that it's designed to delete the notification when the requesting D-Bus client exits, so tools like `dbus-send` and `qdbus` won't work because they exit immediately after calling `requestView`.

If you use `qdbusviewer` to create a request, you can play around with calls like these and it'll work, but I'm skeptical that you'll find anything ready-made which you could call from a shell script to hold the connection open for you.

```
# Assuming qdbusviewer got /JobViewServer/JobView_15 from the call...

qdbus org.kde.kuiserver /JobViewServer/JobView_15 org.kde.JobViewV2.setInfoMessage 'Frobnicating the foobles...'
qdbus org.kde.kuiserver /JobViewServer/JobView_15 org.kde.JobViewV2.setDescriptionField 1 Cromulence fair
qdbus org.kde.kuiserver /JobViewServer/JobView_15 org.kde.JobViewV2.setPercent 25
qdbus org.kde.kuiserver /JobViewServer/JobView_15 org.kde.JobViewV2.setSpeed 200
qdbus org.kde.kuiserver /JobViewServer/JobView_15 org.kde.JobViewV2.setTotalAmount 100000 bytes
qdbus org.kde.kuiserver /JobViewServer/JobView_15 org.kde.JobViewV2.setProcessedAmount 200 bytes

qdbus org.kde.kuiserver /JobViewServer/JobView_15 org.kde.JobViewV2.terminate 'Received Ctrl+C'
```

However, if you're willing to use a little Python instead of shell script, I can provide an example which *does* work and I can vouch for Python as a very nice alternative to shell scripting for the same tasks.

Here it is, written to demonstrate as many of the relevant features as possible without setting up an event loop:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

# This line opts into some Python 3.x features if you run Python 2.x
# and must go at the top of the file because it changes how the file is parsed.
# (Specifically, the Python 3.x print() syntax and sane division)
from __future__ import print_function, division

# These lines are analogous to `source` in a shell script
# The `import` statement searches `sys.path` for the requested packages
import fnmatch, os, subprocess, time

# I'm not sure what package you'll need on OpenSUSE, but this comes from
# python-dbus on Debian, *buntu, and Mint.
import dbus

# -- Get a handle for the D-Bus API to create a new Job --

session_bus = dbus.SessionBus()

# A simple little helper function to paper over some complexity
# See Also: https://dbus.freedesktop.org/doc/dbus-python/doc/tutorial.html
def get_dbus_interface(name, path, interface):
    obj = session_bus.get_object(name, path)
    return dbus.Interface(obj, dbus_interface=interface)

create_handle = get_dbus_interface(
    'org.kde.kuiserver', '/JobViewServer', 'org.kde.JobViewServer')

# -- Create a Job and get a handle to manipulate it --

# requestView takes (appName, appIconName, capabilities)
# https://lists.freedesktop.org/archives/xdg/2008-April/009410.html
# ...but according to the source code, capabilities never got hooked up, so
# the pause and stop buttons will always be there, whether or not you're
# listening for them. (And stop will always kill the popup.)
request_path = create_handle.requestView('MyTestApp', 'download', 0)
request_handle = get_dbus_interface(
    'org.kde.kuiserver', request_path, 'org.kde.JobViewV2')

# -- Set up a fake task for demonstration purposes --
files = os.listdir('/etc')  # NOTE: Check out os.walk() for recursive
file_count = len(files)
wait_per_file = 5.0 / file_count  # Add 2 seconds to the total runtime

# -- Configure the bits of the popup that won't change in our example --
request_handle.setInfoMessage('Echoing files in /etc')
request_handle.setTotalAmount(file_count, 'files')
request_handle.setSpeed(200 * 1024**4)  # 200 TiB/s

# -- Do our fake work --

# NOTE: In Python, indentation outside of () and [] is significant
try:
    for position, filename in enumerate(files):
        # Visible in the collapsed view
        request_handle.setPercent((position / file_count) * 100)
        request_handle.setDescriptionField(0, 'Source', filename)
        request_handle.setDescriptionField(1, 'Destination', filename)

        # These are for the expanded view
        request_handle.setProcessedAmount(position, 'files')

        # Here's some fake work so you can see how to call subprocesses
        subprocess.call(['echo', filename])
        time.sleep(wait_per_file)

    # Set the final state of the popup that will be left behind
    request_handle.setDescriptionField(0, "", "Completed successfully.")
    request_handle.clearDescriptionField(1)
    request_handle.terminate("All done")
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print("Ctrl+C Pressed")
    request_handle.setDescriptionField(0, "Cancelled", "Ctrl+C Pressed")
    request_handle.clearDescriptionField(1)
    request_handle.terminate("Cancelled from outside")
finally:
    # This gets called no matter what
    print("Doing fake cleanup")

print("%s of the files were *.conf" % len(fnmatch.filter(files, '*.conf')))
```

Comment: You dont happen to know where to find a list of the app icon names such as the one you use on your `request_path = create_handle.requestView('MyTestApp', 'download', 0)` line do you?

Comment: haha nevermind. it apparreny draws from your system theme. (breeze-dark in my case) i found and searched a bunch of hard to navigate forlders starting at `/usr/share/icons`.

Comment: @DeveloperACE If it helps, the [XDG Icon Naming Specification](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/icon-naming-spec/icon-naming-spec-latest.html) lists the icon names which should be common among all themes.

Comment: yeah I saw that but I tried searching for the ‘download’ icon you used in your example and couldn’t seem to find it through searching the page so I just ended up searching my system instead

Comment: Ahh. My mistake in picking something not part of the spec for my example then. For anyone who does this, you're ideally supposed to check how it looks in all the major themes in use by distros and include a fallback of some sort. (The [Tango icon theme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tango_Desktop_Project) is specifically intended for this purpose, being released into the public domain so you can bundle and modify its icons easily and designed around a style guide intended to make its icons get along with all major icon themes.)

Comment: Nice, I put you code in a easier usable python class: https://gist.github.com/syntion/e75851088b1c9400b6dafcdbfb191990

Answer (score 0):

I modified your python script in order to run a bash command with a progress indicator. You don't see progress but you can see if something is still running.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# This line opts into some Python 3.x features if you run Python 2.x
# and must go at the top of the file because it changes how the file is parsed.
# (Specifically, the Python 3.x print() syntax and sane division)
from __future__ import print_function, division

# These lines are analogous to `source` in a shell script
# The `import` statement searches `sys.path` for the requested packages
import subprocess, time

# I'm not sure what package you'll need on OpenSUSE, but this comes from
# python-dbus on Debian, *buntu, and Mint.
import dbus

# Get command line parameters
import sys

# Run bash script in background
import threading

# -- Get a handle for the D-Bus API to create a new Job --

session_bus = dbus.SessionBus()


# A simple little helper function to paper over some complexity
# See Also: https://dbus.freedesktop.org/doc/dbus-python/doc/tutorial.html
def get_dbus_interface(name, path, interface):
    obj = session_bus.get_object(name, path)
    return dbus.Interface(obj, dbus_interface=interface)


def run_bash_command(command):
    try:
        subprocess.call(command, shell=False)
    except Exception as e:
        print("Exception: ")
        print(e)


def main():
    create_handle = get_dbus_interface(
        'org.kde.kuiserver', '/JobViewServer', 'org.kde.JobViewServer')

    # -- Create a Job and get a handle to manipulate it --

    # requestView takes (appName, appIconName, capabilities)
    # https://lists.freedesktop.org/archives/xdg/2008-April/009410.html
    # ...but according to the source code, capabilities never got hooked up, so
    # the pause and stop buttons will always be there, whether or not you're
    # listening for them. (And stop will always kill the popup.)
    request_path = create_handle.requestView('bash', 'download', 0)
    request_handle = get_dbus_interface(
        'org.kde.kuiserver', request_path, 'org.kde.JobViewV2')

    # -- Configure the bits of the popup that won't change in our example --
    request_handle.setInfoMessage(sys.argv[1])

    # NOTE: In Python, indentation outside of () and [] is significant
    try:
        worker = threading.Thread(target=run_bash_command, args=[sys.argv[1:]])
        worker.start()
        #        for position, filename in enumerate(files):
        #            # Visible in the collapsed view
        request_handle.setPercent(0)
        request_handle.setDescriptionField(0, 'Command:', str(sys.argv[1]))
        request_handle.setDescriptionField(1, 'Arguments:', str(sys.argv[2:]))
        while worker.isAlive():
            time.sleep(1)

        # Set the final state of the popup that will be left behind
        request_handle.setDescriptionField(0, "", "Finished.")
#        request_handle.clearDescriptionField(1)
        request_handle.terminate("All done")
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        request_handle.setDescriptionField(0, "Cancelled", "Ctrl+C Pressed")
        request_handle.clearDescriptionField(1)
        request_handle.terminate("Cancelled from outside")
    finally:
        # This gets called no matter what
        pass


main()
```